# Save date in SQL Server without minutes and hours

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to save a date from a datetimepicker to SQL server database as duration of an user deactivation but i only want to save day month and year. 
Here is my function so far:

```
Public Sub DeactivateUser(user As String, duration As Date)
    Dim query As String
    Dim startdate As Date = Date.Parse(Date.Now)
    query = "Update SC_User Set Us_duration='" & duration & "','" & "Us_Start='" & startdate & "Where Us_User='" & user & "'"
    Access.ExecuteQuery(query)
    query = "Update SC_User Set Us_Inactive" & 1 & "Where Us_User='" & user & "'"
    Access.ExecuteQuery(query)
    MessageBox.Show("User deactivated")
End Sub
```

This doesn't work but shows my idea.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support partial dates, as far as I know.

Comment: Do you want a duration or a date? Those are two different things.

Comment: This is a ridiculous statement: `Dim startdate As Date = Date.Parse(Date.Now)`. Why would you want to parse a `Date` to a `Date`? The point of parsing is to create a `Date` from a `String`.

Comment: I was thinking on  comparing "Duration" variable with the "Stardate" variable also stored. Is there any other way ? (im a newbie)

Comment: If you need the start date and end date then store those values.  If what you need is a duration in days then you can just store that number.  That said, you have to know the start date and end date in order to calculate that number, so that might require storing the start date if it needs to be remembered for some time before the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want today's date without the current time then you use `Date.Today`.  If you want the date without the time from an arbitrary `DateTime` value then you use its `Date` property, e.g.

```
myDate = myDateTime.Date
```

Note that the `Date` property still returns a `DateTime` but with its time portion zeroed.  Not surprisingly, the `Date.Today` property is implemented like this:

```
Return Date.Now.Date
```

If you want to store just a date without time in SQL Server then you should use the `date` data type, which doesn't store time.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whatever format you would like by using a string for the date:

```
Dim startdate As String = Now().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
query = "Update SC_User Set Us_duration='" & duration & "','" & "Us_Start='" & startdate & "Where Us_User='" & user & "'"
Access.ExecuteQuery(query)
```

This, of course, would give you what the time is with just months, days, and years.

Answer (score 0):

datetimepicker can return the base date

```
dtPicker.Value.Date
```